# Is there a non-Rosetta app for Snow Leopard similar to Hotspot Shield?

Tags: software-recommendation, vpn

Is there any application similar to Hotspot Shield that I can use in Snow Leopard without requiring Rosetta?

For those who don't know, Hotspot Shield provides a VPN access so you can browse anonymously on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't rely on the same system, but the [Tor Project](http://www.torproject.org/) can provides you anonymity while connected to the internet.

It fully works under Snow Leopard without Rosetta.

**WARNING :**

> With this kind of softwares, the final node of the system (last Tor node or the VPN company) can, technically (understand "if it wants"), see all your data going through it !
>
> The system grants anonymity not secure connection !
>
> The connection is secured between you and the last node at the minimum, the rest depends on you.
>
> So, always use secure connections (SSH, SSL/TLS, …) when using these systems.
>
> By the way, the same principle apply with your ISP, you just have to choose someone to trust !